# Django lock a file to prevent concurrent access

Tags: python, django

I'm new at Django, just wondering how can we lock a file in Django, when concurrent users want to edit a file? I use the django.cores.files.locks but it doesn't work

This is what I did:

```
with open(filename,"r+) as f:
   locks.lock(f, locks.LOCK_EX)
   f.write(input_text.encode(utf-8))
   ..... (some processing)
   locks.unlock(f)
   f.close
```

anyone has an idea?

Cheers,

Comment: Hi hcyu151, first of all welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd love to help, but as it is now, it's hard to see what the actual problem is. Could you elaborate on the current and expected behaviour? Note that if your system or python dialect doesn't support filelocking, `locks.lock` will return `True` without doing anything. In that case, `locks.LOCK_SH == locks.LOCK_NB == locks.LOCK_EX == 0`, so you should check that.

Comment: What I expect was the file could not be edited when the file is being process, and after the file is processed, the waiting input can go edit the file. How can I check that my system support filelocking or not? Cheers !

Comment: If you're using windows, mac or a popular linux distribution with CPython that won't be a problem. If the `LOCK_##` constants aren't all `0` you'll be fine. Do you expect all processes to not be able to edit the file, i.e. mandatory locking? If so, that requires a whole different level of locking. Otherwise, a lock is an advisory lock, and only prevents other processes from acquiring their own lock. Open up two shell and try to get a simultaneous lock on the same file. If you can't, the locking works fine.